# How to open an .exe file with a .txt file as an argument using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, file-io, arguments

I'm mapping the output from .exe file to my java application. Some of the .exe files accept arguments as .txt file. If the .exe file does not require .txt file as argument, I get the output from it while running using ProcessBuilder().start(). But if it requires the .txt file as argument, the .exe file does not give any output. The .exe file is generated from c program.

```
Process process = new Process() {
    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public InputStream getErrorStream() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int waitFor() throws InterruptedException {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public int exitValue() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
};

if(bench.equals("bank")) {
    process = new ProcessBuilder("./ref/tinySTM/test/bank/bank", "-n"+thread_count, "-d20").start();
}
else if(bench.equals("kmeans")) {
    process = new ProcessBuilder("./ref/stamp/kmeans/kmeans", "-m40", "-n40", "-t0.05", "-i random-n2048-d16-c16.txt", "-p"+thread_count).start();
}
else{
    System.out.println("Error. Invalid benchmark "+bench);
    System.exit(0);
}
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
while ((op = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(op);
}
input.close();
```

Executing bank gives proper output, but executing kmeans does not give any output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing kmeans is printing an error message on stderr but you're not reading from `process.getErrorStream()` so the message is lost. There is at least one problem here:

```
"-i random-n2048-d16-c16.txt"
```

You need to either pass two arguments:

```
"-i", "random-n2048-d16-c16.txt"
```

Or, if kmeans will accept them together as one, get rid of the space:

```
"-irandom-n2048-d16-c16.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

To add on to what Kugelman said, depending on where the file is you might have to use an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, and make sure text file in the location, Hope it helps

instead of writing I/O to SYSTEM OUT manually you could inherit with process builder in following manner

```
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder= new ProcessBuilder("./ref/stamp/kmeans/kmeans", "-m40", "-n40", "-t0.05", "./ref/stamp/kmeans/kmeans/random-n2048-d16-c16.txt", "-p"+thread_count);

        processBuilder.inheritIO();
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why this helps.  Also, all of those lines can be replaced with processBuilder.[inheritIO()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29).